# How to create variables using rows from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a file like this:

```
<?php
$cssMainVersion = "1.0.3";
$cssBootStrapVersion = "1.0.1";
$cssElseVersion = "1.0.4";
$jpgVersion = "1.0.1";
$jsMainVersion = "1.0.1";
$jsElseVersion = "1.0.1";
?>
```

I have created a mySQL table that holds the variable name, and the variable data. For example, the first row contains `"cssMainVersion"` and the second row contains `"1.0.3"`.

How would I loop thorugh each row and print that data in a new file according to the format above?

Comment: Can you share the query you are using?

Comment: Iterate over the row, pull the key and the value. Use the key for the name and value for the value.

Comment: Why not store that in a neutral data format like JSON, YAML or even an INI file and use built-in functions to read it in? Storing data as code is often highly problematic.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, here: "SELECT id, cachename, cacheversion FROM cache"

Comment: @tadman I am echoing the variables out in code later.

Comment: I highly suggest you use the variable names as keynames in a controlled array, than do it with straight up variable names like that. As tadman said, you can get into serious issues and problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create variables dynamically with php

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT id, cachename, cacheversion FROM cache');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $$row['cachename'] = $row['cacheversion'];
}
```

the `$$` will be evaluted from right to left, so, first `$row['field']` will be replaced with this value, let say `cssMainVersion`, then we have `$cssMainVersion`

Comment: This code is full of extremely serious risks as it allows someone to arbitrarily overwrite any variable they want.

Comment: This does unfortunately not work for me. When I try this: $$row['cachename'] = $row['cacheversion']; it does not create a variable. When I try to echo a variable later, there is no data for that var.

Comment: If you echo immediatly after the while loop, it doesn't work? It works in this example: https://3v4l.org/0mmFY

Comment: There was an extra space in `'cacheversion '`